# Fishnet in MapInfo

Tags: mapinfo, vector-grid

I have a data set of equally spaced geocoded points (10KM apart). Is there a way to turn this into a grid of square polygons around the points? Someone mentioned that ArsGIS has an easy way to build such a fishnet. But does this exist in MapInfo? If not, how is this done in ArcGIS, if anyone knows?

Comment: Create Fishnet is the name of the tool in ArcGIS for Desktop.

Comment: Thanks @PolyGeo, do you by any chance know if there is a MapInfo equivalent?

Answer (score 2):

The GridMaker tool can help you get there.

GridMaker can create polygon grids for a given area.
This is how the Grid Maker dialog looks:
[image]

The result from the Grid Maker looks like this:
[image]

Now if you want to convert this to points, you can use the MapBasic window to convert the polygons to points, using this statement:

```
Update Grid Set OBJ = Centroid(OBJ)
```

[image]

Comment: ah, I think I misread what you are trying to do. This might not be the solution you are after

Comment: Actually, using GridMaker should make it pretty easy. Just work out the coordinates of the bottom left and top right extents of the grid you want to create (lower left point  - 5km N and E and upper right point +5km N and E) and set the spacing to 10km.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort of do this by selecting your points, making a destination layer editable (where you want to create your fishnet) and using Objects > Voronoi. You will probably need to deal with edge points as I believe it will treat them as the maximum boundary for these objects. Adding an additional row/column of points around the full boundary of your point grid and then deleting the resulting outside grid objects is a workaround though.

e.g.

[image: MapInfo grid using voronoi]